# How to detect edges for pattern on space?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm building a new machine and have a problem with edge detection. I have a piece of paper put on one cylinder as shown in the image below. How to detect edges of this paper?

[image]

I attempted to build a led background but this paper is very large. Therefore, my machine don't have enough spaces to run.

Comment: you can implement edge detection algorithm first and then segment it. Hopefully, this idea will help you.

Comment: Is that the original image with the axes? If not could you add the original image? one idea is to use `cv2.inRange()` to segment colors then use Canny edge detection to obtain the contour

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as a reference. Here, I am basically using `cv2.inRange` function to segment light green color from the image(not dark green, otherwise edge of one of the axis will also be detected) and finally applying `Canny` edge detection on the grayscaled version of the segmented image, i.e., `cv2.Canny`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread('cylinder.png')

# convert to HSV color space
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Threshold the HSV image to get green colors by defining range of green color in HSV
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, (36,0,0), (55,255,255))

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)

# coverting image with green colored region of interest from HSV to RGB
img_hsv2bgr = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# coverting image from RGB to GRAYSCALE
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv2bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 100, 200)

cv2.imshow('Edges', edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output:

[image]

EDIT: After making some modification to above code, like segmenting yellow color portion along with light green color and applying Gaussian blurring before passing into the `cv2.Canny` function gives even better output than above.

Code:

```
# Threshold the HSV image to get both green and yellow colors by defining range of color in HSV
mask_green = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, (36,0,0), (55,255,255))
mask_yellow = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, (21, 39, 64), (38, 255, 255))
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask_green, mask_yellow)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)

# coverting image with green colored region of interest from HSV to RGB
frame_hsv2bgr = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# coverting image from RGB to GRAYSCALE
frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_hsv2bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gaussian_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame_gray,(5, 3), 0)

# canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gaussian_blurred, 100, 200)
```

output:

[image]